# Unable to infer default Android SDK settings. This is fine, just run npx cap open android and import and sync gradle manually

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

i'm using ionic project with angular
when I write  `ionic capacitor add android`
I get this error message

Error running gradle sync
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not open proj generic class cache for build file '/Users/macbookshop/Desktop/rp/android/app/build.gradle' (/Users/macbookshop/.gradle/caches/7.0/scripts/ay3p
> wbb15u1).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 61

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1s

Unable to infer default Android SDK settings. This is fine, just run npx cap open android and import and sync gradle manually
✔ Syncing Gradle in 2.21s
[success] android platform added!
Follow the Developer Workflow guide to get building:
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/basics/workflow

Comment: Did you run  npx cap open android ?

Comment: yes , I get this error message in android studio
Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: This might be related to licenses issues for Android SDK. Ensure that you've accepted and agreed to all Android SDK requirements.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?